# Question about List<T>

Tags: c#

I have a list with data:

```
public List<Client> AddClients( )
{
    List<Client> clients = new List<Client>();
    clients.Add(new Client()
    {
       Name = "MyName",
    });
    return clients;
}
```

My question is how could I make a method to add a new Name in the same List?

Comment: Sometime I wonder if I don't understand because of my bad english or because the asker is unclear.

Comment: What do you mean by "add a new name?" Do you mean "add a new Client?" @Jean it's not you.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand your question.

You can add a new name on the return list.

For example

```
var myList = AddClients();

myList.Add(new Client()
    {
        Name = "NextName"
    });
```

You could also change clients to accept a name array to add the clients.

```
public List<Client> AddClients(IEnumerable<string> names)
{
    List<Client> clients = new List<Client>();

    foreach(var name in names)
    {
        clients.Add(new Client()
        {
           Name = name,
        });
    }

    return clients;
}
```

Then call it like

```
var myList = AddClients(new[] {"MyName", "NextName"});

// My list contains both MyName and NextName
```

Comment: Is that C#? Looks like JQuery to me.

Comment: you can't use array initializer in a parameter. It can only be used in “field declarations, local variable declarations, and array creation expressions”.

Comment: you can change it to `new [] {"MyName", "NextName"});`

Answer (score 1):

The question is unclear, but it sounds like you want to do something like this:

```
public void AddClients(List<Client> clients, string name)
{
    clients.Add(new Client()
    {
       Name = name,
    });
    return clients;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat unclear, but assuming that you want to use this method to add names to a list, you should pass the list as a parameter:

```
public List<Client> AddClients(List<Client> clients )
{
    clients.Add(new Client()
    {
       Name = "MyName",
    });
    return clients;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking what I think you're asking (which I'm not sure about at all :) ), then try this:

```
public List<Client> AddClients( )
{
    List<Client> clients = new List<Client>();
    clients.Add(new Client()
    {
       Name = new Name("myname"),
    });
    return clients;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all help. But I think I have to clarify my question a little bit:

Comment: I just want to add a new name using same methode in same list. It means that I already have Myname in clients List. Next timne I want to add Yourname to the same client List. How could I do it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the same method to pass another name. See the modified method below that accepts a string parameter where you can pass the name.

```
public List<Client> AddClients(string strName)
{
    List<Client> clients = new List<Client>();
    clients.Add(new Client()
    {
       Name = strName,
    });
    return clients;
}
```

So you would then call

```
AddClients("MyName");
AddClients("MyName2")
```

;